# How can I compute a Jacobian matrix with dual quaternions?

Tags: quaternion, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to understand an inverse kinematics algorithm realized with [dual quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion) as presented [here](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://www.thinkmind.org/download.php?articleid=intsys_v6_n12_2013_5&ei=YW8MU-HoHKSO7QaB3IHQDA&usg=AFQjCNEgMMmN_98kP3uwVWoKIq57dJyvbg&bvm=bv.61725948,d.bGE).

My [Jacobian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), however, seems to be calculated wrong. Could somebody explain, step-by-step, how I would compute a Jacobian matrix with dual quaternions so that I can check my implementation?

I've read dozens of papers that cover dual quaternions but it's all theory. I'd love to see is an example (e.g. for a single one-, or two-linked chain).

Comment: So it boils down to apply the procedure given in appendix B, section B, figure 8 on page 65 of your cited paper to some problem `e = f(w_1, w_2)` for two joins `w_1` and `w_2`.

Comment: Sorry, I solved this weeks ago! Wasn't aware of this question  would still be alive...thank you very much!

Comment: Hummingbird, could you close the question then? Thanks!

Comment: How can I do this? Nothing in FAQ, I tried to delete it but it isn't possible. Sorry for that stupid question..

Comment: @Hummingbird You could answer it. :)

Comment: +1 for answering it for the rest of us, it's only polite not to leave us hanging!

Comment: Basically it's all explained in the paper, only thing I didn't know was how to apply this algorithm on the last page. If you have explicite questions please ask me!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is localized to the specific implementation of a specific paper.